# Change Code to .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

It seem that .net 2.0 do not support OrderByDescending for dictionary keys , **how can I change this code to .net 2.0**

```
    private static Dictionary<byte[], Func<BinaryReader, Size>> imageFormatDecoders = new Dictionary<byte[], Func<BinaryReader, Size>>()
 {
     { new byte[]{ 0x42, 0x4D }, DecodeBitmap},
     { new byte[]{ 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x37, 0x61 }, DecodeGif },
     { new byte[]{ 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61 }, DecodeGif },
     { new byte[]{ 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A }, DecodePng },
     { new byte[]{ 0xff, 0xd8 }, DecodeJfif },
 };


public static Size GetDimensions(BinaryReader binaryReader)
     {
         int maxMagicBytesLength = imageFormatDecoders.Keys.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).First().Length;
         byte[] magicBytes = new byte[maxMagicBytesLength];
         for (int i = 0; i < maxMagicBytesLength; i += 1)
         {
             magicBytes[i] = binaryReader.ReadByte();
             foreach (var kvPair in imageFormatDecoders)
             {
                 if (magicBytes.StartsWith(kvPair.Key))
                 {
                     return kvPair.Value(binaryReader);
                 }
             }
         }
         throw new ArgumentException(errorMessage, "binaryReader");
     }
```

Comment: Eh? The OrderByDescending call should be fine in .NET 3.5... but why would you expect moving to 2.0 to solve the problem? And where do you expect `byte[].StartsWith` to come from?

Comment: @oded - sounds like a missing using *directive*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
int maxMagicBytesLength = imageFormatDecoders.Keys.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).First().Length;
```

just gets the length of the longest byte array in the keys of your dictionary. So just iterate through your items in `imageFormatDecoders` and record the longest value, i.e., something like this (untested):

```
int maxMagicBytesLength = 0;
foreach (byte[] magicBytes in imageFormatDecoders.Keys) {
    if (magicBytes.Length > maxMagicBytesLength)
        maxMagicBytesLength = magicBytes.Length;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you , you are in right way , but how can I handle byte[].StartsWith in dot net 2.0 ?

Comment: @Ata: Move the foreach loop outside the for loop. Inside the foreach loop, make a loop that compares the first `kvPair.Key.Length` items.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you simply lack;

```
using System.Linq;
```

At the top of the code file. And no, switching to .net 2 won't help here.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that .net 3.5 does not support `OrderByDescending`. It does. And by the way what is wrong with `Max(x => x.Length)`?

Comment: Hi, thank you , can you explain what you want to use for this ?

Comment: @Ata: `int maxMagicBytesLength = imageFormatDecoders.Keys.Max(x => x.Length)`.

Comment: You are wrong , dot net 2.0 do not allow me to use dot net 3.5 component .

Comment: WTF, you started by saying that you were using .net 3.5. I can see that you have changed your question now, but I must admit that I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this, in .Net 3.5?

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dict[0] = 2;
dict[1] = 3;

foreach (var item in dict.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Output

> 1
>
> 3
>
> 0
>
> 2